# List # of objects in directory and add them together

Tags: python-2.7

I was trying to add variables that were giving the number objects in a directory and add them together

```
import commands    
fuzzer1 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/windows/browser | wc -l")

fuzzer2 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/windows/os | wc -l ")
fuzzer3 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/mac_os/browser | wc -l ")
fuzzer4 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/mac_os/os | wc -l")
fuzzer5 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/linux/browser | wc -l")
fuzzer6 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/linux/os | wc -l")
fuzzer7 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/misc/browser | wc -l")
fuzzer8 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/misc/os | wc -l")
module1 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/modules/scanning | wc -l")
module2 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/modules/dns | wc -l")
module3 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 /usr/haxxor/modules/enumeration | wc -l")
list_fuzzers = (fuzzer1 + fuzzer2 + fuzzer3 + fuzzer4 + fuzzer5 + fuzzer6 + fuzzer7 + fuzzer8)
```

but I kept getting a sum of 100000

Comment: You're adding strings (`commands.getoutput` returns a string).  You problem would be better solved using `os.listdir` or `os.walk` if you can describe what you *actually* want to do.  Are you wanting to count everything under `/usr/haxxor`?

Comment: I have a basic banner and I want to count the number of files under subdirectories such as /usr/haxxor/fuzzers/windows/browser and add that to the amount to the other numbers of files to get a grand total

Comment: I got it working using os.lisdir thanks for the help!